# Purple Mushroom Identification

Tags: species-identification, mushroom

I found a purple mushroom that looked like this on a nature walk in South Carolina, USA today. This is not my picture, but one that looks exactly like the mushroom I saw. I have searched the internet, but I could not identify it. Does anyone know what this could be?

[image: Purple Mushroom]

Comment: This Q is too broad: Mushroom identification is very difficult, even with an original picture. The picture you provided is from a relatively rare mushroom. There are much more commen purple mushrooms, like Laccaria amethystina for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you used is from a [Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/mycology/comments/2ig8iw/what_is_this_purple_mushroom_found_at_deception/), where the mushroom is identified to be Cortinarius violaceous. More information on Cortinarius violaceous can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortinarius_violaceus).

Although it could be a different mushroom, as the picture you provided is not a picture of the specific mushroom you saw.

Another picture of Cortinarius violaceous
[image]
Source: [velutipes.com](http://www.velutipes.com/natural/cortinarius_violaceus1.jpg)

All credit goes to Reddit user tubergibbosum for the identification.